# Reading Avro files in GCS as PCollection<GenericRecord>

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, avro, apache-beam-io, beam

Our Dataflow job, written in Python, listens from a Pubsub subscription. The messages are strings of GCS file path of Avro files (`gs://bucket/file-timestamp.avro`). The avro files are not of uniform schema, but Beam Python's `avroio.ReadAllFromAvro` is good enough to parse generically the records of the avro file in GCS as dictionaries.

```
# Python code
pipeline
    | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)
    | "Read Avro Files" >> avroio.ReadAllFromAvro(with_filename=True)
```

The expected form of the resulting PTransform is a tuple: `(same_gcs_filepath, record_as_dict)`

Because of some limitations in Python, we need to convert our code to Java. We can read from Pubsub alright, however, we don't know yet how to use `AvroIO` in order to get a resulting `PCollection<GenericRecord>` without specifying a schema.

```
// Java code
pipeline
  .apply("Read from Pub/Sub", PubsubIO.fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()))
  .apply("Read Avro Files", AvroIO.__________________)
```

It would be better if the original `gcs_filepath` is passed along with it just like what we do in Python. Do I need to use `FileIO` in tandem with `AvroIO`? How do I achieve this?

**Update:**

```
pipeline
  .apply("Read from Pub/Sub", PubsubIO.fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()))
  .apply("Read Avro Files", FileIO.matchAll())
  .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
  .apply(AvroIO.parseFilesGenericRecords(record -> record))
```

The code above lead me to some progress, but then it is complaining that I should be providing a coder

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to infer coder for output of parseFn. Specify it explicitly using withCoder()
```

which in the last line should look like this:

```
  .apply(AvroIO.parseFilesGenericRecords(record -> record).withCoder(someCoder))
```

But then, `someCoder` requires a specific schema, which I can't really provide as the incoming avro file can be of different schema.

Comment: Hi @oikonomiyaki, Can you try using the read class as mentioned in this [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html) ? Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ShipraSarkar It requires a coder though, which in the example in the documentation is not specified.

Comment: Hi @oikonomiyaki, Can you try using [parseGenericRecords](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html#parseGenericRecords-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction-) ? Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To read a PCollection of filepatterns whose schema is unknown at pipeline construction time or differs between files, you can use [`parseAllGenericRecords(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction<org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord, T>)`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.html#parseAllGenericRecords-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction-)

In your case, your serializable function can just return the GenericRecord

For example:

```
 Pipeline p = ...;

 PCollection<GenericRecord> records =
     p.apply(AvroIO.parseAllGenericRecords(new SerializableFunction<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>() {
       public GenericRecord apply(GenericRecord record) {
         // If needed, access the schema of the record using record.getSchema()
         return record;
       }
     }));
```

Comment: It requires a Coder in the withCoder method.